# "Нет-нет, да..." — как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в таком предложении: "Нет-нет, да оглянется назад..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конструкции типа "нет-нет и", "нет-нет да и" считаются устойчивыми сочетаниями, внутри которых не ставится запятая: *Павел нет-нет да и вспоминал о своей спокойной жизни дома. Он нет-нет да оглянется. Она нет-нет и прослезится.*

Их нужно отличать от присоединительных конструкций: *Я не любил ходить в школу, да и никто из нас не горел желанием.*

Answer (score 1):

Я встречал такую фразу с союзом "да и". Там запятая ставилась, так как союз был присоединительный, а в Вашем предложении союз "да" скорее в значении "и", поэтому запятая, по-моему, не нужна